# laravel more than one result from single query

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get all rows and distinct column from single query. but paginate method is only giving result but not pagination option like total prev next etc..

```
$offers = Offer::whereHas('users', function ($q) use ($authUser) {
                    $q->where('user_id', $authUser->parent_id);
                    $q->where('publisher_id', '=', $authUser->id);
                });
```

and distinct column

```
$websites = $offers->distinct()->get(['website']);
```

with pivot columns (just wanted to show my full query)

```
$offers->orderBy($sortBy, $orderBy)->paginate($perPage)->map(function ($offer) {
            if (!empty($offer->users)) {
                $manager = $publisher = '';
                foreach ($offer->users as $user) {
                    $manager   = $user->pivot->user_id;
                    $publisher = $user->pivot->publisher_id;
                }
                $offer->manager   = $manager;
                $offer->publisher = $publisher;
            }
            return $offer;
        });
```

Return

```
return response()->json([
            'offers' => $offers,
            'websites' => $websites
        ], 200);
```

hope my question will make sense.
Thanks.

Comment: `$offers` and `$websites` seems to be independent of each other in your response. Which one doesn't have working pagination?

Comment: website is a column of offers, i just want to distinct value of website for filtering purpose and offers result with paginate.

Comment: Can you try to call `->getCollection()` before your `->map(function ($offer)` ?

Comment: @christophe-hubert your suggestion worked. Please enter your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @AbdulShakoorKakar Answer added, and glad it helped 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run `getCollection()` before mapping to get the paginator's underlying collection.
(https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html#method_getCollection)

```
$offers->orderBy($sortBy, $orderBy)->paginate($perPage)
            ->getCollection()
            ->map(function ($offer) {
            // ...
            return $offer;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering based on it being `$offers`:

Your usage of `map()` is copying the modified results of your `paginate()` call to a new collection and that collection does not include the pagination information. That's why you no longer have pagination information.

Since there result of `paginate()` is already a usable collection, you can use `each()` instead of `map()` which will alter the objects in-place.

Comment: thanks for your answer,
I tried your solution but some how each is returning boolean.